# How to add a style to an object property

Tags: javascript

I'm a JS learner. I managed to access an object property but I would like to style it, for example - change its color.

```js
const houseForSale = {
    material: "brick",
    size: "4 bedrooms",
    condition: "excellent",
    characteristic: "red roof"
}

const message = document.querySelector("#demo");

let styleFragment = houseForSale.characteristic;
styleFragment.style.color = "red";

let text = "The house has a " + styleFragment + ".";
console.log(text);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

When I do that, I get an error message: "can't access property 'color', styleFragment.style is undefined.

Comment: Objects don't have `style` properties unless you give them one. The "characteristic" property of your object has a simple string value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text nodes (and plain strings) are not styleable - they don't have a `.style` property. Either create a string of HTML markup as well as, say, a `<span>` with a style:

```js
const houseForSale = {
  material: "brick",
  size: "4 bedrooms",
  condition: "excellent",
  characteristic: "red roof"
};

const text = "The house has a <span style='color: red'>" + houseForSale.characteristic + "<span>.";
document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Or explicitly create an element first, then assign to its `style` property.

```js
const houseForSale = {
  material: "brick",
  size: "4 bedrooms",
  condition: "excellent",
  characteristic: "red roof"
};

const p = document.querySelector("#demo");

p.appendChild(document.createTextNode('The house has a '));

const span = p.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
span.textContent = houseForSale.characteristic;
span.style.color = 'red';

p.appendChild(document.createTextNode('.'));
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```